# How to update one g:select using another in Grails

Tags: grails

I'd like to update content one `g:select` by another. I use `remoteFunction` but it doesn't work. When I select value from departments nothing happpens. I'm using Grails 2.4.3

SubjectInfoController.groovy

```
class SubjectInfoController {

def create(){
        institutes: Institute.listOrderByName(order: "asc"),
    }

def updateInstitutes(){
        def department = Department.get(params.int('department'))
        [institues: department.institutes]
    }

}
```

create.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="bootstrap-main" />
<title>SARNA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <div class="container">


            <label for="department.id" class="col-md-3 control-label">Wydział
                </label>

                <g:select name="department.id" class="form-control"
                    from="${Department.list(order:'asc', sort: 'name')}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name"
                    value="${department?.id}"
                    onchange="${remoteFunction(controller: 'SubjectInfo', action: 'updateInstitutes', update:'institutes', params:'\'department=\' +this.value')  }"
                    />




            <label for="institute.id" class="col-md-3 control-label">Instytut
            </label>

                <g:select name="institute.id" id="institutes" class="form-control"
                    from="${institutes}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name"
                    value="${institute?.id}"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Console errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/SARNA/js/application.js 404 (Not Found) create:261
GET http://localhost:8080/SARNA/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js 404 (Not Found) create:20
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined create:36
onchange
```

Comment: do you have console errors ? is #institutes replaced with something ? how does the response look like

Comment: @johnSmith, I edited, I have console errors. I didn't understand your second question, and I don't know how can I check how response look like ;(

Answer (score 0):

okay, so the ${remoteFunction ..} most likely generates some Jquery-code

and as your jquery.js is not found / not properly included, the request fails

there should be no problem if jquery is included

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes I had `<head><g:javascript library='jquery'/></head>` and it should be `<head><g:javascript library='jquery' plugin="jquery"/></head>`.